# Use of undeclared type 'CostumTableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode7.3

I experienced a problem with the code I'm working, please help me in this matter

[image]

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as CostumTableViewCell
```

Comment: You r using xib I think ? If yes the U have to load xib first then U can declare like this

Comment: clean and run once

Comment: There must be a custom class `CostumTableViewCell` or maybe it's just a typo `Costum` vs `Custom`

Comment: @Jecky This has nothing to do with using a xib or not.

Comment: If this cell is been created in tableview then U dont have to give as custom class. You can directly use it by giving identifier.  Try to give class in IB

Comment: Have you created a class `CostumTableViewCell` that inherits from `UITableViewCell`?

Answer (score 0):

please check if you include :

1- `import CostumTableViewCell`

2- also must add question mark ? after as .

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CostumTableViewCell
```

if not work try add ? after CostumTableViewCell?